# Magento 1.9 - No upload image buttons

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, image-upload

I am building my first Magento store, but I found out that I can't add images to products. It is testing site, so I am learning how things are functioning in Magento.

I tried almost everything - reinstalled flash, shockwave, browsers, updated prototype... No luck.I tried in 5 browsers.

Is there anything elese I can do to try to fix it?

[image: Here is a print screen]

Comment: Opera has lost its Flash... Hopefully Magento 2 is smarter than to require it.

Comment: Try this html5 solution: https://www.mavenecommerce.com/2016/10/18/magento-html5-uploader/

Answer (score 21):

I found this issue when I had extended and created my own theme for the admin area.

These buttons use FLASH.

So if your browser does not support flash - then they will not appear.

Ensure that the `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media` folder exists and that there are 2 files within it.

- editor.phtml
- uploader.phtml

Ensure that the `skin/adminhtml/default/default/media` folder exists and that there are 3 files within it.

- flex.swf
- uploader.swf
- uploaderSingle.swf

If you have created your own theme (ie Theme: "mytheme" and Package "mypackage") then ensure the above applies for:

- `app/design/adminhtml/mytheme/mypackage/template/media`
- `skin/adminhtml/mytheme/mypackage/media`

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This happens, if you are using git and you are writing the line media/ instead of /media to the .gitignore-file.

Comment: Please note that this answer is outdated. You should NOT have the .swf files anymore in your media folder for security reasons.

Comment: Update - this fix should only work for pre 2.0 versions.

Answer (score 5):

These buttons are coming from flash.So check your media folder on following location

design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media

if there is no media folder then copy from fresh magento

This will solve your problem :) if not Try solution from below links
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15022532/image-upload-buttons-are-missing-in-magento-in-back-end

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/v/viewthread/55646/

Answer (score 4):

Funny thing, i had the same kind of problem in the project i currently work, but all files were in place (Talking about Magento Version 1.14.1.0).

First i thought the issue are the missing '' here

```
var maxUploadFileSizeInBytes = <?php echo $this->getDataMaxSizeInBytes() ?>;
```

found in several places, for example in

- "app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media/uploader.phtml"
- "app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/cms/browser/content/uploader.phtml"

But that lead to a new error, so the final solution was to change the php.ini like that:

```
upload_max_filesize = 100 M
```

to

```
upload_max_filesize = 100M
```

Answer (score 4):

I tried all the solution,but still i was not able to resolve this problem.

I ***got it resolved by downloading the Adobe flash for the browser (Firefox) that worked for me.***

Comment: It is coming for product images but not for CMS page editor.

Answer (score 3):

Edit your `/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media/uploader.phtml`

```
var maxUploadFileSizeInBytes = '<?php echo $this->getDataMaxSizeInBytes() ?>';
var maxUploadFileSize = '<?php echo $this->getDataMaxSize() ?>';
```

replace with

```
var maxUploadFileSizeInBytes = '128M';
var maxUploadFileSize = '128M';
```

Comment: How would this help with displaying the buttons? It looks more like uploader files missing or Flash not working properly

Comment: The problem here was not getting the size from "getDataMaxSizeInBytes()". So when i manually given the size the buttons were displayed automatically.

Answer (score 2):

There is three thinks:
- HHVM (misconfiguration)

Copy

> /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Media/Uploader.php

to

> /app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Media/Uploader.php

and replace :

```
public function getPostMaxSize()
{
    return ini_get('post_max_size');
}

public function getUploadMaxSize()
{
    return ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
}
```

to:

```
public function getPostMaxSize()
{
    $post_max_size = ini_get('post_max_size');
    return $post_max_size ? $post_max_size : ini_get('hhvm.server.max_post_size');
}

public function getUploadMaxSize()
{
    $upload_max_filesize = ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
    return $upload_max_filesize ? $upload_max_filesize : ini_get('hhvm.server.upload.upload_max_file_size');
}
```

- Files - https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/71693/35766
- Configuration PHP - upload_max_filesize = 100M

This is finally solution to fix problem entirely.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I fixed it like this:
in chrome enter the following url

chrome://settings/content

You will see a popup, scroll down until you see flash, select ***allow sites to run flash***.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the product image upload button not loaded in Magento CE 1.9.2.1, I had to add `'` character in `maxUploadFileSizeInBytes` value.

Change

```
var maxUploadFileSizeInBytes = <?php echo $this->getDataMaxSizeInBytes() ?>;
```

To

```
var maxUploadFileSizeInBytes = '<?php echo $this->getDataMaxSizeInBytes() ?>';
```

In

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media/uploader.phtml
```

Answer (score 1):

Please update the browser and install latest flash player...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Git, make sure your .gitignore file doesn't inadvertently exclude Shockwave Flash files.

My .gitignore had the line:

```
*.sw?
```

Which was supposed to exclude *.swp, *.swo, etc but I hadn't thought about *.swf at the time.

So I changed it to:

```
*.sw?
!*.swf
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue, and it was because I wanted to control my unsercure & secure base urls for front & admin from within my local.xml

So if your unsecure & secure base urls is controlled with your local.xml you might run into this issue. I have not had time to work on a fix for this yet

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem on Magento 1.9.2.3 with HHVM. I discovered that the problem was from HHVM. Switching to PHP5-FPM solved the problem for me.

Comment: can you please explain me how can i switch to PHP5-FPM?

Comment: There is an article for installation php5.6-fpm here: https://tecadmin.net/install-php5-on-ubuntu/. You would need to replace the HHVM address or socket with that of php5.6 after the installation.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Following is what fixed the issue for me:

In app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media/uploader.phtml

> Replaced getUploaderUrl('media/uploader.swf') ?> with the exact path of the uploader.swf https:///skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf