# Magento Upload Images missing (Firefox only)

Tags: magento-1.7, php

I came across an issue, basically when I am trying to upload a product image in the magento admin panel. I dont see the upload button. After some searching, I realized its a flash issue, Firefox stopping supporting flash.
Currently only Chome and IE support it.
Similar post: [Magento 1.9 - No upload image buttons](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53352/magento-1-9-no-upload-image-buttons)

Next month, new version of chrome will stop supporting Flash, how do we go about uploading Product Images? I assume chrome will hide the upload button, just as Firefox does.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your web browser uses flash, the image uploader in Magento uses flash witch is no longer active in the most up-to-date web browsers.

To fix this there are two options:

Option 1:

Install a non flash upload plugin like the one below:

https://github.com/openstream/No-Flash-Image-Uploader

Option 2:

Install flash on your machine, the downside to this solution is that you will need to install flash on every machine you or your clients use to upload images.

That's why option 1 probably is the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Patch 8788 will replace the flash image upload. You could also upgrade to Magento 1.9.3.0 but the upgrade step takes some more time.