# How to add product image in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcdP6.png]

Magento 1.9 there is no upload option?

Comment: please install the flash player  so that you will be able to upload the image aswell  check the same in other browsers also.

Answer (score 2):

Hello this issue is caused by Flash player 
You can refer to this thread https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/71693/49821

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This issues causes due to lack of Flash player.

So, Please download the flashplayer and install. Then you can get the options for browse image and upload image.

Answer (score 0):

[How to add product image in magento 1.9](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/157452/how-to-add-product-image-in-magento-1-9)

Question 1 : How to add product image in magento 1.9
Answer : These buttons use FLASH.

So if your browser does not support flash - then they will not appear.

Ensure that the app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media folder exists and that there are 2 files within it.

editor.phtml
uploader.phtml
Ensure that the skin/adminhtml/default/default/media folder exists and that there are 3 files within it.

flex.swf
uploader.swf
uploaderSingle.swf
If you have created your own theme (ie Theme: "mytheme" and Package "mypackage") then ensure the above applies for:

app/design/adminhtml/mytheme/mypackage/template/media
skin/adminhtml/mytheme/mypackage/media
I hope this helps.