# Can't upload images in magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: error, upload, magento1.9.2.4

[image: error upload picture]I want to upload product pictures, but this option does not work. Although it appears they were charged nothing happens, they do not appear. The phone works on loading, but on any PC browser does not work.
Any ideas?
Please help!!

Comment: please make your question more clear

Comment: After uploading photos in the gallery product , pictures do not appear, and there is no error. It is empty as would not be upload.

Comment: and what about that phone part in your question

Comment: if using admin page on your phone, it is possible to upload pictures but does not work on any pc ,  I attached a picture of the main message with error on pc

Comment: take a look here, there are a lot of good suggestions on things to check: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53352/magento-1-9-no-upload-image-buttons

Comment: upload and browse buttons appear and function but does not load the picture and upload_max_filesize = 100M is set to 512M 
I checked other files
app / design / adminhtml / default / default / template / media folder exists and That There has 2 files Within it.

editor.phtml
uploader.phtml

AND ARE OK

I don't know what I can do

Answer (score 0):

This may be a problem with file permissions or perhaps the browser you are using.  I would try to use Firefox or Chrome or Safari and see if another browser on your desktop is able to upload the images.  If your mobile phone can upload images, its probably not a file permission issue on the server.  I would certainly verify that nginx/apache or whomever is the set as the file owner for your server has write permission to /path-to-magento/media/.

Comment: Only safari works, chrome, firefox or Internet explorer doesn't work .