# Theme installed on local host isn't showing Product images

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, product-images, localhost

I have uploaded the Quick-start package of the theme on my localhost server but when i opened any product details from **Manage Products** section to make modification there is no option for uploading or adding  of images.
I want to add images to my product.

Please help me to solve this.[image]

Comment: try in different browser or check in console for any error.

Comment: what is magento exact version you are using?

Comment: @RamaChandran the theme quick-start package i have installed show Magento version 1.9.1.0

Comment: @ Marius sure i will always put source. i forgot for this

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult for us to help you on this one, because we don't know what theme you are using, and it's unlikely many people will be very familiar with it.

Why don't you use the built-in tool to import images?

You only have to put all your images in `media/import` and create a CSV with `SKU` and the relevant images `base_image`, `small_image`, `thumbnail` ... on the following columns

Comment: I m using sm-g3shop Magento theme. Actually its not showing upload tab for adding any images.

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood your request. Those buttons use Flash so your browser need to support. Have a look there: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53352/magento-1-9-no-upload-image-buttons . If it still doesn't work for you, disable the modules your custom theme and check if they appear.