# Product Image Browse/ Uploading option not showing?

Tags: magento-1.9, chrome-browser, browser

When I uploading the products images not showing and browse and uplaoding option also disabled in google chrome and opera mini. Its uploading images properly inside mozaila firefox browser.

I am new in magento. Please help me to resolve issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not in Magento. Flash player is not working in chrome. Please Install flash in chrome and test it will work.

Otherwise please upgrade to new version or Install all patches latest patches. 
SWF files are remove in supee-8788 patch.

Comment: Thanks Dude, Problem resolved by update the adobe flash player, but in opera mini, browse/uploading options are disabled

Comment: Sir, I am facing Again same error,  now,only working fine in opera mini. in chrome/ Mozilla unable to upload(browse/ uploading options hide) and one more question i want to learn magneto in deep level . i have good knowledge of html, css and bootstrap. i am waiting your reply.

Comment: study  http://excellencemagentoblog.com/ , and alanstrom blog http://alanstorm.com/category/magento-2/ is enough i think. 

check link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53352/magento-1-9-no-upload-image-buttons

Comment: Sir, I want to change product inventory from in stock to out of stock at once. how will do? Bcoz, one by one takes lot of time, want to save time.

Comment: I have product category of juuties and clothes. i want to customize first all jutties display after that display rename clothes or first display all clothes after that display rename jutties on same category page.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a issue of Magento and its because of Flash player plugin in browsers.

If its working in mozilla that it means its working. Issue with browser only. Upgrade your chorme to latest version.

Comment: Thanks Dude, Problem resolved by update the adobe flash player, but in opera mini, browse/uploading  options are disabled.

Comment: Good to know that.

Comment: Sir, I am facing Again same error, now,only working fine in opera mini. in chrome/ Mozilla unable to upload(browse/ uploading options hide) and one more question i want to learn magneto in deep level . i have good knowledge of html, css and bootstrap. i am waiting your reply.

Comment: plz clear cache manually from magento and also from browser .

Comment: Sir,  I manage whole e commerce multi designer fashion website. today, i create GST Tax Classes as per indian law for different - different products(ex: footwear, carpets, sarees, jewelery, dresses), but i am confusing if somebody place order on website from out of country, GST will applicable or not for international orders.

Answer (score 1):

Install supee-8788 patch it will resolve your problems. As i already faced this type of issue.

Please follow below links
https://magentary.com/kb/install-supee-8788/

Answer (score 0):

If you're having problem with product image upload button missing in the backend of Magento (it’s missing "Browse Files" and "Upload Files" buttons and none of the images are showing up – Product Image Uploader broken).

Please try the following solutions to fix that via (*OIW Blog* - ohiwilldotcom):

**– Solution 1:**

Go to media folder (/media) in the root directory and delete or rename .htaccess file.

**– Solution 2:**

This can be caused by wrong permissions of media folder, so please set CHMOD media folder (/media) to 775 at least (or 777), if this didn’t work please try again to CHMOD all of folders in media folder.

**– Solution 3:**

Check Flash Player is installed in your browser or not. If not then install Flash Player and allow sites to run flash (this on the left of address bar of your browser of you can set up it in Setting of browser).

**– Solution 4:**

Please check if media folder is here or not. If not please copy media folder from default Magento version and put it there (media folder should exist in the following below folders and all of files in it):

```
/skin/adminhtml/default/default
/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/system/config/system/storage
/js/tiny_mce/plugins/
/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/
```

Hope this helps.