# Flash player Down unable to upload image

Tags: magento-1.9

in magento admin dashboard i unable to upload image due to **flash player down**. Please advise the option for adding of product images.

Comment: Please check this post if it helps! https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53352/magento-1-9-no-upload-image-buttons/53357

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a duplicate question

Answer:

Flash uploader was removed to being insecure and replaced with javascript uploader. Please apply the correct patch 8788 or update the store to 1.9.4.5 / OpenMage Project to avoid further disruption.

Answer (score 0):

I just built a basic Node.js CLI tool for image uploading based on [this](https://github.com/MadisonReed/magentoapi) repo/module. This is for a legacy install that is still running 1.5x and is full of gremlins that prevent patching from working properly. It uses the old SOAP API.

I used [Commander](https://github.com/tj/commander.js#readme) to add CLI options.

I used [Pkg](https://github.com/vercel/pkg#readme) to create executables.

It's a pretty simple project that allows non-technical users to quickly add images to a product by SKU.

```
'use strict';

const Mage = require('./node_modules/magento');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const { program } = require('commander');

program
    .version('0.1')
    .option('-s, --sku <sku>', 'Base SKU to upload to')
    .option('-f, --file <file>', 'Image filename')
    .option('-l, --label <label>', 'Image label')

program.parse(process.argv);;
const options = program.opts();

function mageUpload() {
    
    var session = new Mage({
        host: 'www.example.com',
        port: 80,
        path: '/api/xmlrpc',
        login: 'yourlogin',
        pass: 'yourpassword'
    })
    return session.login(function(err, sessId) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('error on login', err);
            return;
        }
        
        var filename = options.file;
        var image = fs.readFileSync(filename);
        var base64img = image.toString('base64');

        session.catalogProductAttributeMedia.create({
           product: options.sku,
           data: {
               file: {
                   content: base64img,
                   mime: 'image/jpeg',
                   name: path.parse(filename).name
               },
               label: options.label,
               types: [],
               exclude: '0'
           }
        }, function(self, result) {
            console.log(self);
            console.log(result);
        })

    })
}

mageUpload();
```

Comment: Just going to add that there is a bug with this approach and I haven't tracked it down precisely yet. It may be related to the `xmlrpc` dependency of the `magento` npm module, or it might just be a server resource configuration error. 

When I upload images over a certain size, I get an error coming from `xmlrpc` unable to parse the `TITLE` element, which tells me that the SOAP API response is throwing some kind of error and it's in the form of an HTML page, which cannot be parsed properly by `xmlrpc`. 

I suspect the PHP config has some inadequate resources configured.